# How to send files to aspx with ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, webforms

Im trying to make an ajax post request to an aspx that is supposed to handle my file uploads. However when i read the requests Files, it contains no files.

```
public partial class SaveFile : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public bool isSaved = false;
    [HttpPost]
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the files from the request
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var files = request.Files; <---- this is empty when it should have files

        //temporary path until put on server
        string basePath = @"C:\Users\ClonePC\Desktop\UploadedFiles";

        //write each file to the disk and save it to the mongodatastructure
        foreach (HttpPostedFile file in files) {
            SavedFile sf = new SavedFile();
                            
            var fileType = file.ContentType;
            var fileNameOnDisk = $@"{sf.UID}.{fileType}";
            var fullPath = $@"{basePath}\{fileNameOnDisk}";

            sf.FileName = file.FileName;
            sf.FilePath = fullPath;

            var byteStream = file.InputStream;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(byteStream);
            byte[] byteArr = br.ReadBytes((Int32)byteStream.Length);
            File.WriteAllBytes(fullPath, byteArr);
        }
        isSaved = true;
    }
}
```

this is my ajax request

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log(this.response);
};
xhr.open('POST', PathProvider.GetRooPath() + "/SaveFile.aspx");
console.log(formData.getAll("files"));
xhr.send(filesAdded[0]);<--any generic file
```

Comment: Check the `network` tab in your browser and examine the Request Payload of your request and tell us what you see. Also add the JS where you define the `filesAdded` array and `formData` instance.

Comment: Looks like there's a typo in the `xhr.open` line - `GetRooPath`.